# color coding rows based on what text is in a column in Microsoft Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In the image below, if I type `Win` or `Loss` into column A, I want the text in columns B:P to turn Blue (win) or Red (loss) automatically. Can this be done?

An example of what I want Excel to do:

[image: An Example of what i want Excel to do]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Excel 2016, but here are the steps that work in 2010 and I assume they're the same in 2016 (other than the visual aspects).

1. Select columns A-P and then choose "Conditional Formatting" from the menu
2. In the conditional formatting choose to use a formula to control the text formatting

   [image: Column selection screen shot]
3. Enter the formula for blue text as `=$A1="Win"` and the formula for red text as `=$A1="Loss"`
   [image: New rule screen shot]

   When you're done your conditional formatting formulas should look like this:
   [image: Conditional formatting formulas screen shot]
4. Now select any rows you don't want formatted (ie. header rows) and remove the conditional formatting from that row.

<sub>*(Updated per [@Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott)'s feedback in the comment thread.  Anyone, looking at the comments can disregard the `=INDIRECT(..` garbage I'd used before. Thanks, Scott)*</sub>

Comment: All you need to do is use `=$A1="Win"` and `=$A1="Loss"` in your conditional formatting formulas.

Comment: @Scott Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that require you to enter `=$A1="Win"`, `=$B1="Win"`, `=$C1="Win"` ... on each row?  Otherwise wouldn't all the rows base their color off of the single `A1` cell value?

Comment: To elaborate, I know that copying and pasting `$A1` across several cells makes the row component (`$A`) stick and only the column component will update relative to the cell being copied into.  But, that's never been my experience in the conditional formatting formulas.  They seem to almost be an afterthought that doesn't get much attention.  This same feature is seemingly just as neglected by Google's in Google Sheets.

Comment: You’re wrong.  (Sorry, but you asked me to.)  Two points: (1) Your question doesn’t make sense.  Why would you ever want to check cell `B1` or `C1` for `"Win"`, when all the Win/Loss entries are in column A?  I presume you mean `A2`, `A3`, etc.  Even in your second comment, you’re tied in knots.  You refer to `$A` as being the row component, when, of course, it is the column. (2) I was going to explain what `$` does in cell references, but I see you understand that, so let me just say: Yes, this works in conditional formatting formulas.  (And it’s been my experience that it has always worked.)

Comment: Yeah.  Rows... columns... Too late in the evening.  I do know the difference (as you pointed out).  Just don't play in Excel much anymore so I'm not as fluent as I used to be.  I'll correct my answer tomorrow after I give it a whirl and verify everything.

Comment: @DavidWoodward
Okay I figured it out. I had to tinker with it for a while but I got it by putting =A1="Win" in Z3 and in Y1-200 putting 
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 1))="Win"

Comment: @DavidWoodward tried to edit that last comment but it wouldnt let me. Anyway i got it working but now the top column i was using to lable W/L, Champ, Role, ect is red now. how can i fix this?

Comment: @DavidWoodward Figured it out as well lol Again thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  But, just so I'm clear on what worked (so I can update my answer) what is the conditional formatting formula that worked?  From what you said, Z3 and Y1 are the same thing. (And `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 1))="Win"` in Y1-200 could just be `=$A1="Win"` if you want to clean things up a bit - they're equivalent). But, it's not clear what's in your conditional formatting formula.

Comment: @Scott I've updated my answer with the details you provided.  Sorry for the initial confusing answer Jonathon. (Thanks for teaching me something new Scott)